# android Date parsing

Tags: android, date, timezone

I have the following string i need to parse to a date:

```
2012-01-31T08:41:12.5462495+01:00
```

now i have tried the following code which doesn't work:

```
public static String FORMAT_DATE_ISO = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

public static Date fromISODateString(String isoDateString) throws Exception {
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DATE_ISO);
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Zulu"));
    return f.parse(isoDateString);
}
```

i am assuming its becase the time zone should be something like +0100 and in my case it is +01:00.

how do i solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The time zone specifier
- The precision of your seconds

I haven't found an easy way to fix the time zone specifier part in `SimpleDateFormat`, so I'd be tempted to just manipulate the string - it's a fixed length, so it's not hard to remove the final colon. Then you can use

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"
```

as your format string. Note that according to the [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) *does* handle time zone offsets using colons, so that's another option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jon Skeet for the format string.

i have managed to replace the last colon using

```
 isoDateString = isoDateString.replaceFirst("(.*):(..)", "$1$2");
```

so the working code for this will be:

```
public static String FORMAT_DATE_ISO = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ";

public static Date fromISODateString(String isoDateString) throws Exception {
        isoDateString = isoDateString.replaceFirst("(.*):(..)", "$1$2");
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DATE_ISO);
        f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Zulu"));
        return f.parse(isoDateString);
    }
```